# Help installing Ubuntu Cinnamon or linux Mint to a standalone system with a single drive

Tags: system-installation, cinnamon

I've downloaded Ubuntu Cinnamon from Ubuntu site using a USA mirror and downloaded Linux Mint Cinnamon version and tried a number of times to install them.

I created a usb flash drive using both Rufus and Unetbootin.

When the flash drive boots I get a menu of 5 options, first one Ubuntu Cinnamon, so I take that option.

I then get two options "Try Cinnamon" or "Install Cinnamon" First three times I took Install Cinnamon.

I tell it to erase and write to drive.  However, I can't remember if it ever tells me the specs of the drive. I did just remove the drive and look at it on a Windows machine and it does have a Linux installed.

I used the normal installation option and told it to install updates.  It takes almost all day to do this. On the last install it did more things than I've seen before like running APK something and loading a bunch of AMD stuff. Which made me think at the time it worked.

When it gets done I take the restart option, but it never does tell me to remove flash drive, but it does reboot and then starts all the options again.

I checked the bios and I have to Boot options "UEFI P4...." and just "P4 ...." . "P4" is the assigned sata slot for the motherboard. I've tried both.

If I try to boot from "P4" it says I created it using Rufus and I need to change it to "MBR" and "Bios", even though the last 2 installs I used UNETBOOTIN.

The last install per something I found earlier was use the "Try Ubuntu" and then when  I get to the Desktop take the option to install Cinnamon there instead, which I did but same outcome.

As I sit here I almost think ubuntu install faked me out and did the install to the flash drive and not the hard drive.

Right now I think I'm going to reformat the drive and recreate the flash drive from scratch and see what happens, but I will check back to see if someone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

And just for the record obviously I'm new to linux.  My experience was Unix. I've been a programmer for 45 years. Yes, I'm old.  I hate Windows. I'm finally fed up with Windows updates and want to go to something that doesn't screw up my miners.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please be clear and precise with details; what OS & specifically what release are you asking about; eg. Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.10 ?   FYI:  I learn Unix in the early 80s myself; and liked GNU/Linux when it appears much much later, as I could just treat it as a Unix (*like*) system & I was home...  Ubuntu products/flavors use different installers, with more than one option available for some releases; but you've given no specifics (Linux Mint isn't on-topic here, this is a Ubuntu Q&A Support site)

Comment: Also what hardware are you installing into. And what video card/chip? Is not P4 the USB flash drive. For UEFI install you use UEFI P4 and for old BIOS install (not recommended) just P4. Unless very old system that had early UEFI, may BIOS be better. And is UEFI firmware the latest version?